# Библиотечный модуль в андроид

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

Есть приложение для андроид и есть библиотечное приложение для андроид. Среда разработки - eclipse.

2 вопроса:

1) как правильно включить в библиотечное андроид-приложение классы из обычного проекта Java? В папке с библиотечным проектом я сделал обычный линк для папку src проекта java. Т.е. у меня есть папка src, где находятся исходные коды библиотеки андроид и папка src_link - это ссылка на другой проект. Это правильно?

2) Как правильно подключать андроид-библиотеку к обычному проекту андроид-проекту? Дело в том, что раньше я пользовался только классами, которые создавал в библиотеке и использовал их в нескольких проектах андроид. Теперь я решил попробовать добавить в библиотеку ресурс. Например создал стиль объекта.

Попытался применить этот стиль к элементу. Среда разработки не увидела стиля из библиотеки. Я попробовал задать объекту этот стиль вручную. Ошибок не было, но стиль не применился. Никакой реакции.

В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Вариант заменить `eclipse` на современную среду разработки не рассматривается?

Comment: впервые слышу что eclipse не современная среда разработки

Comment: Помимо того что `eclipse` просто уступает по функционалу и удобству Intellij и Android Studio, Google прекратило поддержку `eclipse-adt` после релиза Android Studio. Это указано и на странице загрузки `eclipse-adt`, и в android-developers блоге.

Answer (score 1):

По 1. Включить Java-классы из "обычного" проекта можно сделав из них Android Lybrary-проект и подключив в виде библиотеки.

По 2. Библиотеку можно подключить через project-Properties->Build Path->Configure Build Path->Add External JARs...
[документация  здесь](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)

Comment: Для начала тот способ о котором пишите вы, не подходит для проектов андроид. Так подключаются библиотеки в стандартных проектах Java. Во вторых как производить рефракторинг когда, когда подключена уже скомпилированная библиотека?